# Print string in one line

Tags: python, string

I asked a question about this earlier but noone could answer me - I have this code and want what is defined as e to be written into a new ASCII file in one line. I was suggested to use the tuple function which didn't work since it only takes on argument but I have two (a and b). So now I just tried the join function. The code is below

```
we=open('new.txt','w')
with open('read.txt') as f:
    for line in f: 
         #read a line
         a,b=line.split('\t')
         #get two values as string
         c=2*int(a)
         d=3*int(b)
         #calculate the other two values
         ### edited
         e = ''.join(("(",str(a),",",str(b),")"))
```

However, when I print e the last bracket will be moved to a new line:

```
        print(e)
```

will yield

```
     (1,2
     )
     (3,4
     )
```

but I want

```
     (1,2)
     (3,4)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `line = line.replace("\n", "")` before further processing the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like b has a `\n` (a newline character) at the end.  `b.strip()` will return `b` with all of the whitespace on both sides removed.  You could replace
`a,b=line.split('\t')` with 
`a,b=line.strip().split('\t')`

or replace `e = ''.join(("(",str(a),",",str(b),")"))` with `e = ''.join(("(",str(a),",",str(b.strip()),")"))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `\n` in your lines before extracting your values. This should give the desired output:

```py
with open('read.txt') as f:
    for line in f: 
         # read values
         a, b = line.replace("\n", "").split('\t')
         # get and parse values
         e = ''.join(("(",str(2*int(a)),",",str(3*int(b)),")"))
         print(e)
```